# Typescript class with generic type that cannot be itself

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-constraints

Is it possible to prevent nested use of a class with a generic type parameter, i.e., `Optional<Optional<string>>`? Example class:

```js
export default abstract class Optional<T> {
  abstract get hasValue(): boolean
  abstract get value(): T

  static of<U>(value: U): Optional<U> { return new FilledOptional<U>(value) }
  static empty<U>(): Optional<U> { return new EmptyOptional<U>() }
}
```

This abstract class has no constructor to limit instance creation. The exact implementation of `FilledOptional` and `EmptyOptional` classes that `of` and `empty` use don't seem relevant.

And this is invalid: `class Optional<T extends Optional<unknown> ? never : T>`.

Is there some way to practically do this at the global class level, or do I just have to decorate every possible method parameter in this class and related classes with a similar type constraint?

Just now I realized the possibility of some `instanceof` checking in the `of` method, but that won't help with the `empty` method.

Or, is it best to simply let this class be used in any possible way, even though (in my mind), a directly nested `Optional` is for now an anti-pattern I'd like to avoid in the codebase.

Comment: TypeScript has no negated types so there's no perfect way to say "`not` Optional<any>`, but you can approximate it like [this maybe](https://tsplay.dev/Wv83kN).  Does that meet your needs? If not could you edit in a [mcve] that shows the failed use cases?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for the input. That's very interesting. I hadn't realized that one can use `never` in that position. Despite a bit of error-message awkwardness, this seems to work, so long as I don't need other objects with a `hasValue` getter property...

Comment: @ErikE This article https://catchts.com/type-negation might be interesting for you